# c# Linq and Xml Reading

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AS3_S5_CraigFenton
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<House> houseListings = new List<House>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttongetListings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                XElement root = XElement.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                foreach(var House in root.Elements("House"))
                {
                    House h = new House();

                    h.HouseCode = House.Element("HouseCode").Value;
                    h.HouseType = House.Element("HouseType").Value;
                    h.Neighborhood = House.Element("HouseNeighborhood").Value;
                    h.Price = decimal.Parse(House.Element("Price").Value);
                    h.Bedrooms = int.Parse(House.Element("Bedrooms").Value);

                    houseListings.Add(h);
                }

                listViewlistings.Items.Clear();

                var sortedHouse =
                    from House in houseListings
                    orderby House.HouseType, House.Price
                    select House;

                foreach (House h in sortedHouse)
                {
                    ListViewItem listingsItem = new ListViewItem();

                    listingsItem.Text = h.HouseCode;
                    listingsItem.SubItems.Add(h.HouseType);
                    listingsItem.SubItems.Add(h.Neighborhood);
                    listingsItem.SubItems.Add(h.Price.Tostring(0));
                    listingsItem.SubItems.Add(h.Bedrooms.Tostring());

                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Error I am getting is Int.parse can not be converted to .tostring? What am I doing wrong. I am trying to read an xml file and post it to a listview  that has five columns. I have this error to fix and trying to just import the file.

Comment: Can you surround in a try catch and post the stack trace?

Comment: What does the XML file look like?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a 1/2 bathroom or bedroom which is common in real-estate.

Comment: @Craig debug your code and see what is the value of `House.Element("Bedrooms").Value` at the time the error occur

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will evaluate and return a boolean to indicate if your value could be properly parsed or not :

```
int bedrooms;
if(Int32.TryParse(House.Element("Bedrooms").Value, out bedrooms))
{
     // Your parse was successful, so set it
     h.Bedrooms = bedrooms;
}
else
{
     // Otherwise it wasn't in the correct format (a breakpoint
     // here would be useful
}
```

It's likely that the use of any room numbers however might be expressed as a double (e.g. 2.5 Bedrooms or 3.5 Bathrooms) so you might want to consider how you might handle these as those are common scenarios.

Additionally, you have a few calls to `.Tostring()`, which you should ensure that you use the propercasing `.ToString()` to avoid any compiler issues.